# Canonical way to convert Completable to Single?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I have an RxJava `Completable` that I want to execute, then chain to a `Single<Long>`. I can write it like this:

```
return Completable.complete().toSingleDefault(0L).flatMap { Single.just(1L) }
```

but this seems unnecessarily complicated. I would have thought `Completable#toSingle()` would do the job, but if I write:

```
Completable.complete().toSingle { Single.just(1L) }
```

I get errors. Is there a missing function in `Completable` or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Please read the [Getting started](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#non-dependent).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`andThen`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/and-then-when.html) opeator, which will subscribe to the source you send to it after the `Completable` completes.

```
return Completable.complete()
    .andThen(Single.just(1L))
```

As @akarnokd said, this is a case of [non-dependent continuations](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#non-dependent).

In case of your source needing to be resolved at runtime, this would be a [deferred-dependent continuation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#deferred-dependent), and you'd need to `defer` it:

```
return Completable.complete()
    .andThen(Single.defer(() -> Single.just(1L)))
```

Comment: Actually that's not what I needed, but did point me in the right direction. What I need is the [deferred-dependent](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#deferred-dependent) continuation - I need the Single source to be evaluated at runtime, not assembly time, so `.andThen(Single.defer{lfmap.count()})`. I used `just(1)` as an example but in fact my Single source can't be evaluated until after the Completable has completed.

Comment: So what I want is something like this extension: `fun <T> Completable.thenSingle(singleSource: () -> Single<T>): Single<T> {
    return Single.defer(singleSource)
}` so I can write `.thenSingle{lfmap.count()}`

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. Edited my answer for the sake of completeness (pun intended)

Comment: Single.just(Unit) is fine if you use Kotlin

Comment: `andThen` returns a Completable, so I don't understand how you have changed a `Completable` into a `Single`

Comment: `andThen` will return whatever the combined function returns. In the example case, it's return `Single.just(1L)`, so you get a `Single` out of it.

Comment: Thank you, that is true! I had an issue where `.andThen { Single.just(Result.success()) }` still returned a completable, for some reason it was using `public final Completable andThen(CompletableSource next)`

Comment: What happens onError?

Comment: @JohnyTex: unless you add an `onError` handler, the usual RxJava behavior will kick in. Depending on where it happens, your `andThen` won't be executed.