# RxJava2: convert Completable to Single - are the approaches equivalent?

Tags: rx-java2

Given a `Completable` called "completable". I want to convert `completable` to a `Single` providing a default value.

I originally used this approach:

```
completable.andThen(Single.just(defaultValue))
```

A colleague created a bugfix pull request replacing the line with:

```
completable.toSingleDefault(defaultValue)
```

While I have to admit this is easier to read anyway, I'm wondering: is this a bugfix or a refactoring?

Comment: Refactoring, I suppose ;)

Comment: Possibly you may want to read about [Rx Continuations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662480/canonical-way-to-convert-completable-to-single)

Answer (score 0):

the difference is in the error case.

> completable.Single.just(dv): Returns a {@code Single} that emits a specified item.

Always emits Single.just(dv)

> completable.toSingleDefault(dv): Converts this Completable into a Single which when this Completable completes normally, emits the given value through onSuccess.

Emits Single.error() or Single.just(dv) depending on the state of completable

Comment: If `completable` emits an error, in both cases, the error will be emitted. `andThen` is only executed if `completable` completes and is skipped in the error case.